# How can I convert a System.Drawing.Font to a QuickFont.ES20.QFont

Tags: c#, graphics, fonts, opengl-es-2.0

I have a System.Drawing.Font

```
var systemFont = new Font("SomeFontName", 32, GraphicsUnit.Point);
```

and want to convert this to a QuickFont.ES20.QFont.

```
var config = new QFontBuilderConfiguration();
var quickFont = new QFont(systemFont, config);
```

But QFont wants a font path string.

Comment: Why would you rely on a system font, you know there is no guarantee that the same font with the exact same version is used on another computer. Just add the font as a resource to your project (provided you may legally do so, of course) and load it from file. QFont wanting an actual path to a file on disk is the correct way to handle fonts here.

Comment: ok, sounds understandable